# How to display the total number of products in 2 warehouses?

Tags: database, oracle

I have this database:

[image: database diagram]

I have a problem, how to show the total number of products in 2 warehouse, if the products in warehouse 1 don't have in warehouse2 and vice versa

I have tried like this

```sql
select warehouse1.good_count+warehouse2.good_count 
from warehouse1, warehouse2 
join goods on (warehouse1.good_id = goods.id)
and (warehouse2.good_id=goods.id);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: why are you creating separate tables for the warehouses?  That is not a good design.  What happens when you have to add Warehouse #3?

Comment: It's a request from my teacher, warehouse 1 is a nearby warehouse, and warehouse 2 is a remote warehouse. @OldProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

Either you misunderstood what your teacher wants, or your teacher asked the question in a wrong manner.

There should be only one `WAREHOUSE` table with additional column (e.g. `WAREHOUSE_TYPE_ID` whose values would then be "remote" or "nearby" or whichever comes next), possibly making a foreign key constraint to `WAREHOUSE_TYPE` **table**.

You'd then simply

```
select t.warehouse_type_name,
       sum(w.good_count) summary
from warehouse w join warehouse_type t on t.warehouse_type_id = w.warehouse_type_id
group by t.warehouse_type_name;
```

---

I read comments you wrote. The fact that these are physically different warehouses (one in the city and one in its outskirts) doesn't change the fact that **data model is wrong**. Data they represent should be contained in the same table, a **single table** (as I explained earlier).

Because, what will you do when company builds yet another warehouse in some other city? Add another table? **WRONG!**

Anyway, if you insist, something like this might be what you're looking for in this wrong data model of yours:

```
select g.name,
  sum(a.good_count + b.good_count) total_count
from goods g left join warehouse1 a on a.good_id = g.id
             left join warehouse2 b on b.good_id = g.id
group by g.name
```

Comment: As you can see in the picture, I need 2 separate warehouses, and the same product, maybe warehouse 1 with quantity 10, warehouse 2 with quantity 20, I need to total the product from 2 warehouses (sharing the same product id) the result will be 30

Comment: I saw the picture, and I said that I think that it is **wrong**.

Comment: In the assignment, the teacher explains this, warehouse 1 is in the city, warehouse 2 will be larger and outside the city further away, the product obtained will take priority from warehouse 1, and if the product is that is no longer available, will move from warehouse 2 in

Comment: And in asking the province to total 1 product from 2 warehouses, I have trouble connecting 2 warehouses, I can find the quantity of 1 product in warehouse 1, but it will add up to all of them one by one. products in the warehouse 2

Comment: I edited the answer and added some more text. Have a look.